# 16-чная/-ричная система

Tags: орфография, числительные, сокращения

Как правильно? Какое правило?

1.1. 16-ричная система счисления.

1.2. 16-чная система счисления.

Ещё: как правильно?

1.1. Шестнадцат**и**ричная система счисления.

1.2. Шестнадцат**е**ричная система счисления.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• В орфографическом словаре: [шестнадцат**е**ричный](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/101306/%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

•• Из [правила](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99):

> Если в составе сложных существительных и прилагательных есть числительное, то его можно записать в словесной форме (прописью) или в словесно-цифровой форме (цифрой и присоединяемым дефисом существительным или прилагательным). При использовании словесно-цифровой формы записи буквенные наращения после числительных не пишутся.

Трехмерный — 3-мерный, двадцатилетний — 20-летний, десятиведерный — 10-ведерный.

• Ещё есть такие прилагательные:
восьмеричный, десятеричный, пятеричный, семеричный, двадцатеричный...

Общая часть для этих слов — "-ричный", она и добавляется с помощью дефиса к цифрам (это не прилагательное, конечно, но при сокращении именно такая запись): **16-ричный**.
Нечасто она встречается, только в специфических текстах.

[Перевод числа из двоичной (8-,16-ричной) системы в десятичную](https://https:/https://studopedia.org/4-88455.html)
[Числа в 16-ричной системе счисления](http://www.astro.spbu.ru/staff/afk/Teaching/Help/Colorinfo.htm) (Санк-Петербургский государственный университет)
[Представление в 16-ричной системе счисления](https://translate.academic.ru/%D0%B2%2016-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/ru/xx/) (academic.ru)

Comment: Римма, почему-то ссылки не открываются.

Comment: Да, проверила, не открываются. Попробую загрузить еще раз. Европа же...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Петербург открылся. Красота разноцветная!.. Попробуй набрать просто в Гугле (мне теперь тоже не дает).

Comment: Ну да. Это в качестве примером использования такого сокращения, а я думал там правила об этих окончаниях.

Comment: По правилам должно быть прилагательное или существительное, а у нас пока не записанный в словарях, непонятный, но в особых (математических, программных)  текстах используемый "ричный". А если уже ж используемый, то надо определяться — как ближе к норме.

Comment: Пятилетний: пят (корень) + **и** (интерфикс) + лет (корень) + н (суффикс) + ий (окончание).

Answer (score 5):

[**Грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=307952)**:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ШЕСТНАДЦАТ**Е**РИЧНЫЙ (Русский орфографический словарь, сайт [academic.ru](https://lopatin.academic.ru/160589/%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9))